# How do I make Serverside and column sorting working in the same time on DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a DataTable and I would like to display data over several pages. I would like pages with 100 elements on each. In addition I would like to have some of my columns sortable.
In my Database I have more than 100 elements and my DataTable is only showing the first 100...

I've noticed some things :

1) When I put **"bServerSide": false** my columns are sortable ***BUT*** my number of rows is limited to 100 (one page with 100 elements).

2) When I put **"bServerSide": true** my number of rows is now correct (several pages with 100 elements on each) ***BUT*** my columns are not sortable anymore (I mean the sort function doesn't work when I click on the sort button).

```
$('#tableSupervisionElecteur').DataTable({  
        "bLengthChange" : false,
        "bFilter" : false,
        "bProcessing": false,
        "searching": false,
        "ordering":  true,
        "order": [[1, 'asc']],
        "bStateSave": false,
        "pageLength": 100,
        "iDisplayStart": 0,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "initComplete": function(settings, json) {

        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function () {

        },         
        "sAjaxSource": "sourcesDataTables",

        "aoColumns": [
            ...
        ],
        columnDefs: [
                {
                    orderable: false,
                    targets: 0
                },
                {
                    orderable: false,
                    targets: 7
                },
                {
                    orderable: false,
                    targets: 8
                },
                ]
    });
```

I would like to have BOTH features working together (sorting and displaying) and not one or the other.

Furthermore my DataTable needs to be able to handle approximately 30 000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Remove orderable: false for the columns which you need ordering and also specify the order(asc or desc) in "order" option

Comment: I got a total of 8 columns. I have put orderable: false to the columns that I don't want sortable. And I've set "order": [[1, 'asc']] because I need this as "default sorting".

Answer (score 0):

Its depending on your server side, as order is processed on server. Server must check if any request for ***asc*** or ***desc*** and build your database query, each column field sorted base on that.